# OpenCL incrementing integer after each kernel execution

Tags: opencl

I have a kernel that I need to execute multiple times (using `clEnqueueNDRangeEnqueue`), and one of its arguments is an integer that needs to be incremented after each execution.

Rather than have the host assign an incrementing value (using `clSetKernelArg`) before enqueuing each kernel execution, is there a purely "device-side" way to achieve this, e.g. have the kernel increment a global integer itself once the final work item has run? (I'm still new to OpenCL so might be barking up the wrong tree here).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to achieve that on the kernel side but I would not do that, as it may have influence on the kernel performance. Anyway it could be done this way:

```
kernel void my_kernel(__global int* counter, __global int* other_data, ...)
{
    // some operations on other_data, etc.

    // make sure that only one work item increments the counter to avoid race condition
    // the assumption is that kernel uses one dimension only
    if(get_local_id(0) == 0) 
        atomic_inc(counter); // need to use atomic function as kernels may run in parallel
}
```

So to summarize rather than adding branch by making only one work item work and waste cycles of the others I would continue using `clSetKernelArg` and increment counter on the host side. There are operations that are better suited for GPU and incrementing the counter is rather not one of them.

Comment: This does not increment the value when the last work item has run. It increments it whenever the work item with global_id in first dimensions happens to finish.